# OpenCart: Class Loader not Found

Tags: opencart2.x

I am working a project, suddenly my system halted I gave it a reboot and now I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Loader' not found in /var/www/html/projectfolder/index.php on line 29
```

I checked it in system->engine its there

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being stuck for 24 hours I did some research and found out if we have our admin panel on different vhost we can still open that and clear modifications from admin. Once they are cleared, this error is gone and site populates normally.